# If $A$ is a noetherian ring and $a$ is an ideal of $A$, then $A$ and $A/a$ are not isomorphic rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I have started the course in commutative algebra. I am facing problem in how to approach this type of questions. How to think of a mapping between these two rings.
Help me in this case. here ideal is non-zero.